# attribute ref on attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

i want to ref an attribute to an attribute, so i can make a restriction on the user that he won't forget to write an attribute that does not have a same attribute in another tag
example:
invalid:(because there are no tag named `word` that has the attribute `B`

```
<model name="A"/>
<model name="B"/>
<word key="A">
    <value lange="english">Add</value>
    <value lange="frensh">ajouter</value>
</word>
```

valid:

```
<model name="A"/>
<model name="B"/>
<word key="A">
    <value lange="english">Add</value>
    <value lange="frensh">ajouter</value>
</word>
<word key="B">
    <value lange="english">Add</value>
    <value lange="frensh">ajouter</value>
</word>
```

can that be done in xsd ?

Answer (score 0):

This particular use case can be achieved by declaring `model/@name` to be an `ID`, and `word/@key` to be an `IDREF`.

However, an ID must be unique across the whole document, and not rely on element names or position in a hierarchy for disambiguation.  If you have any other elements that use "A" or "B" as an ID, then your document will be invalid.

Different kinds of conditional validation can be achieved using [RelaxNG](http://relaxng.org/), than with XSD, so you might consider using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid you cannot achieve this using XSD 1.0. You can only restrict value of `key` attribute of `<word>` element to have some value present in `name` attributes of `<model>` element like following schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="root_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="model" type="model_type" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:key name="name_key">
                    <xs:selector xpath="."/>
                    <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
                </xs:key>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="word" type="word_type" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="model_type">
        <xs:attribute name="name"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="word_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="value"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="key"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="root" type="root_type">
        <xs:keyref name="name_keyref" refer="name_key">
            <xs:selector xpath="word"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@key"/>
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But it is not possible to enforce all `name` attribute be covered by `name` attribute. In this case I would change the structure because if you have such need it signals the `<word>` elements should be contained in `<model>` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="root_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="model" type="model_type" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="model_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="word" type="word_type" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="word_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="value"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="root" type="root_type"/>
</xs:schema>
```